# Row Bind In sql using UNION ALL

Tags: sql, union-all

I have multiple subqueries with the same columns (`year`, `week`, `value`). My goal is to have a table with all of the years together

My query works, but I have a lot of repetitive code and the query takes a little more time than expected. Am I doing `UNION ALL` correctly?

```
with year15 as(),

year16 as(),

year17 as()

select year, week, value
from year15
UNION ALL
select year, week, value
from year16
UNION ALL
select year, week, value
from year17
```

Comment: If the table(s) in your cte's are all the same, just select and use a where year >=2015 and year <2018

Comment: The subqueries are pulling from different tables.

Comment: In that case, your solution is probably the easiest way.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is meant to display duplicates, should this case be unique every year? thus `UNION` is appropriate

Comment: `UNION ALL` does not attempt to remove duplicates and hence it is faster then using `UNION` which adds an extra step to remove duplicates. So only use `UNION` if you must remove duplicates from the data. In short, your query syntax looks fine but as we know nothing about the data we cannot decide if you need `union all` or `union`.

Comment: The slowness of your current query may have more to do with the 3 cte's than with the use of union|all. Try doing explain plans for each cte independently perhaps. Maybe you need additional indexes?